# Working with CSV file in php

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file which has two comma separated values value1 and value2 already, which will be overwritten every time when I run file1.

This value1 and value2 will be used as params for file1 to get next values, which is grabbed by it's index 0 and 1 from csv.

I need to add file2, that will do the same and write its value as value3 and value4 in the same CSV file i.e when I run file2.

Now what happens is when I run file2 first it overwrites file1 values, I need to make static that index of the CSV 0 and 1 is for file1 and index 2 and 3 for file2. Someone has this answer?

sample code

```
public function writeforFile1($row_write)
{
   $file = fopen('rowsCopiedFile.csv', 'w+');
   fputcsv($file, $row_write);
   fclose($file);


}

//This needs to write on the same rowsCopiedFile, but starts on index 2 and 3.
public function writeforFile2($row_write)
{

   $file = fopen('rowsCopiedFile.csv', 'w+');
   fputcsv($file, $row_write);
   fclose($file);

}

//$row_write will be like ["date", "no.of rows copied"]
```

Comment: Your text is very confusing, do you have any code?

Comment: Please provide some sample code.

Comment: @YogeshSalvi updated the sample code here

Comment: Try a+ instead w+

Comment: It's still very confusing. You add two functions to your question. OK.??? Now what? What are you expecting?

Comment: @A.Meshu I wonder a+ will append everytime, But I need to append only one that is on the first time, next time it needs to overwrite which has previously written at the index 2 and index 3. Hope this is clear..

Answer (score -1):

try using javascript

```
  var csv = [];
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
     for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
      row.push(cols[j].innerText);
      csv.push(row.join(","));  
     }
  }
```

Comment: i need to work on server side, no js. could you help me in php?